# Is it possible to use a user-defined table type in SQL Server like a Struct?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In PostgreSQL, I can do something like this to define and then use a composite type:

```
create type PERSON as (first varchar, last varchar);
select PERSON '("tom", "jones")'
```

And in SQL Server I can also create a custom type by doing:

```
create type person as table (first varchar, last varchar);
```

Is there any way then to use that composite/table-type within a select statement, such as doing:

```
select CAST(('tom', 'jones') AS person)
```

Or something similar?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You have to declare a table variable of the type and then insert into it. The lack of real relation type support in SQL Server has been a grievance of mine for over 20 years.

Comment: just an aside... I don't like varchar without a length   varchar(50)

Comment: You can however create a custom function that returns your type based on your input such as: `select dbo.myFunctionThatReturnMyType('tom', 'jones')`

Answer (score 1):

Table Types are readonly and cannot be modified, you can declare a variable as type of TableType and do insert update which does not actually update the table on which it is created. you can do something like this

```
DECLARE @personType AS person
 
INSERT INTO @personType 
VALUES ( 'tom', 'jones' )

SELECT * FROM @personType
```